# Javascript: InvalidStateError:DOM Exception 11

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have below code that handling the HTTP request. But I am getting

> Error: InvalidStateError:DOM Exception 11

error.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req_settings = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req_settings.onreadystatechange = processChange;
        req_settings.open("GET", url, true);
        req_settings.send();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req_settings = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req_settings) {
            req_settings.onreadystatechange = processChange;
            req_settings.open("GET", url, true);
            req_settings.send();
        }
    } 
    req_settings.onreadystatechange = processChange; 
    req_settings.send();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `send()` twice, which is invalid. Your code should be

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var req_settings = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req_settings = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else
    throw "environment does not support ajax";
req_settings.onreadystatechange = processChange;
req_settings.open("GET", url, true);
req_settings.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I try it but now the code never return any data, it is hanging...

Comment: But that's a different issue. You would need to post what service (url) you are using, what `processChange` is doing, and how you are experiencing "hanging". Maybe a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I end-up restructured the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The code makes no sense, you would be calling

```
req_settings.onreadystatechange = processChange; 
req_settings.send();
```

twice, Does it inside the if and outside of it! Remove the ones inside. Also it should be using the native object. Use a library!